# unmute member in all servers they are in

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make an Unmute command but not in only 1 server, but all of the servers a member is in.

The code I have that doesnt work:

```
async def unmuteAterx(ctx):
  Aterx = 549328259331129364

  if ctx.message.author.id == Aterx:
    for guild in client.guilds:
      member = guild.get_member(549328259331129364)
  
      if member is not None:
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Muted')

        await member.remove_roles(role)
```

(i have it set to only me rn because im testing it)

I get an error: `Command raised exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

Full error:

```
Ignoring exception in command unmuteAterx:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 477, in unmuteAterx
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 720, in remove_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you get error for `ctx.message.author.id` then you should first check `if ctx.message.author is not None`

Comment: im not getting an error for ``ctx.message.author.id`` as i have used it in other commands and it works fine

Comment: you didn't show full error message so I can't see where you get this error - and I see only one `.id` in your code - so I assume you get it for `ctx.message.author.id `. But even if it worked in other command then it doesn't have to work in this command - and you should first check `print( ctx.message.author )` to check it. But if error shows you problem with different `.id` in different place then you have to check it in different place.

Comment: I edited in the full error (i think its the full error), do you think this is enough for you to help me?

Comment: You are getting error because there is no role name "Muted" in some guilds.

Comment: Thanks! I really should've thought about that since I had to do that in some of my other commands...

Answer (score 0):

As @Weylyn pointed out, this happens because the role with the name 'Muted' doesn't exist on all the server in which the bot is.
When this is the case, `discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Muted')` will return `None` so you can check for that before trying to remove the role.

Also this bit of code doesn't remove the muted role of the member on all of **his** servers, but on all the servers **where the bot is**